# How can I build the 64-bit version of the Crypto++ dll?

Tags: c++, dll, 64-bit, crypto++

I'm currently working on implementing the crypto++ libs into a c# app. It's all working fine in 32 bit.
However when I tried to build the c++ DLL in 64 bit, I got this error:

> Error 1 error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Custom Build Step" cryptopp cryptopp

I then changed the project settings to build in Unicode from the default multibyte, and got it to build with no errors. However, it will then fail the safety check when using the `GetPowerUpSelfTestStatus()`.

I've googled the heck out of this, and apparently this is not an uncommon problem. However no one seems to have found a solution, or at least hasn't shared it.

What can I do?

Comment: With a little more debugging I think it might be a linker issue, switching to unicode just lets it think it's a successful build, however it will fail if i recompile, but switching back and forth between multibyte and unicode temporarily allows a compile, although it has some incremental linkage issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the custom build step options under the project preferences. Just change the leading output directory folder from 'Win32' to 'x64' with x64 as your target platform. =/